# Android Studio 1.5 with Kotlin Plugin got exception, when is in debugger mode. How to fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

`10:57:54 AM Plugin Error: Kotlin threw an uncaught UnsupportedOperationException. Disable Plugin
10:57:54 AM UnsupportedOperationException: null`

looks the Kotlin plugin got Exception when encounter the Android studio shows the java stackframe.

Update: I **did** update the kotlin **many days ago**, but the Exception still exists. (don't know the downvotes reasons)

I think maybe `ext version` in gradle build file still using `beta` version, I'll try to change the version in gradle

## Solved

Actually it is associate with `gradle build file`, the IDE error only make me to update the IDE's plugin, not the kotlin extension itself. After change buildscript `ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-beta-4589'`, the problem gone

[image: Bug]
[image]

Comment: There's an update available to the Kotlin IDE plugin.  Perhaps you should update it along with your Kotlin compile dependency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception is fixed in Kotlin 1.0-rc. Please update your plugin and the version of Kotlin in your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I had some kind of circular dependency on an interface inside my class.

I solved it by just looking for errors in my code and fixing them.

This is a kind of tricky one because the error sounds like it is an error in the Kotlin plugin. It is likely just a coding error. So look for the red squigglies and fix them.